# swift - CGImage to CVPixelBuffer

Tags: swift, cgimage, cvpixelbuffer

How can I convert a `CGImage` to a `CVPixelBuffer` in swift?

I'm aware of a number of questions trying to do the opposite, and of some objective C answers, like [this one](http://www.programering.com/a/MTM2IDNwATY.html) but I could not get them to work in swift. Here's the closest I've got:

```
func pixelBufferFromCGImage(image: CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer {
    var pxbuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    let options: NSDictionary = [:]

    let width =  image.width
    let height = image.height
    let bytesPerRow = image.bytesPerRow

    let dataFromImageDataProvider = image.dataProvider!.data
    let x = CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)

    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        width,
        height,
        kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
        CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider),
        bytesPerRow,
        nil,
        nil,
        options,
        &pxbuffer
    )
    return pxbuffer!;
}
```

(this doesn't compile because `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` excepts an UnsafeMutablePointer and `CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)` is an `UnsafePointer<UIint8>!`)

Comment: If you know how to do this in Objective-C, why not write this one method _in_ Objective-C and get on with things?

Comment: Because I'm starting a project in Swift and I'm willing to put the time to get things in that language, and I don't know Objective-C as well (nor am I willing to learn it more that I really have to)

Comment: So is the question how to turn an UnsafePointer into an UnsafeMutablePointer? Because that's not very difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use UnsafeMutablePointer, to do that, you can transform `CFData` to `CFMutableData` and then get **UnsafeMutablePointer** for example:

```
let dataFromImageDataProvider = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, image.dataProvider!.data)
let x = CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)
```

Comment: Just to mention that CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes argument "CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)" should be replaced with "x".